# Save config.xml value on install/upgrade

Tags: magento2, database, admin, configuration, system.xml

I have just created `system.xml` and `config.xml` for my project - they work ok after implementation:

[image: config]

The values don't get written to the database unless I press save in admin though - ran `setup:upgrade` and `setup:di:compile` after implementation and it didn't save it to core_config_data- are these defaults written after any cli commands?

Comment: you mean you want to give default values in cofig.xml?

Comment: I have given values in config.xml already - they are the values you see on the screen